# One CSS File or individual CSS files for each page?

Tags: css, stylesheet

When I am building pages, do I want to have individual stylesheets for each page or one large stylesheet for the entire site? For loading purposes, wouldn't individual files be a better practice because it would be less total css on load?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use a single file, CSS files are cached and therefore reduce the need to download a new file for each new page visited.

To help, I usually process my CSS through a [CSS cleaner](http://www.cleancss.com/) to reduce its file size, additionally, you can [GZip CSS using .htaccess](http://www.samaxes.com/2008/04/htaccess-gzip-and-cache-your-site-for-faster-loading-and-bandwidth-saving/) too, making it smaller yet again.

Finally putting all CSS in a single file will make making system-wide changes to presentation easier in the future (the entire reason we use CSS in the first place), it will also make debugging easier.

**Edit, May 2017**

A lot has changed in 7+ years, and anyone looking at this answer should consider researching newer asset delivery methods, especially now that HTTP2 and preprocessors are more commonplace.

Comment: To avoid having to use too many unique ids and classes to achieve a stylesheet which contains all teh styles for your site it's also a good idea to add a class to the body of each page indicating which page it is i.e <body class="productPage"> will enable you to use the same classes and ids on each page. eg using the above technique you can give the content area on the page a different style by using .productPage #contentArea, so you won't have to put a new id #productPage_contentArea in the page's html.

Comment: How about huge CSS files and memory usage on mobile devices? Is your point still stands in the case of mobile devices, you think? Will huge CSS slowdown user experience on mobile? What do you think about JavaScript files, is it also better to have one?

Comment: Reducing HTTP requests is the number one thing to do when looking to improve performance on a web site. A large CSS file won't take an inordinate amount of time for a mobile browser to parse / render, having to download a larger file will of course take longer, however (generally speaking), it's far more important to have one large file, than many smaller files. Because HTTP requests are slow to get going. Look up anatomy of HTTP request, plus TCP segmentation.

Comment: Interesting, I never knew you could compress stylesheets.

Comment: This idea of a single CSS file is fine if you have a lot of common styling throughout the website. But often you may have dimensional uniformity of say a header + nav bar yet also have different coloring on it for each page, due to needing contrast with the background image that may have different color from page to page. Other elements like article, section, etc may be different in both size and style. All this points towards having a common style and an override for each page. This means 1 CSS download per HTML if we  put the common CSS into the home page and always start from the home page.

Answer (score 10):

A different suggestion, use multiple style sheets during development and have a mechanism which will merge all the style sheets into a single CSS file for production deployment. This may require some bit of extra coding and some extra scripts to be run before production deployment but would be ideal for both development use and production use. If the process is properly automated (which is not very difficult to achieve) this won't cause any kind of mistakes also.

Answer (score 4):

The main purpose of the style sheet is to allow you to alter the design across all your pages. If you have `h1 {color:red;}` on each page and later want to change it to blue you would have to edit each page's style sheet. With one style sheet you would be able to change the color and have that reflected over the entire site.

Plus the style sheet will be cached on the user's computer rather than downloaded from each page.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have a consistent style across all pages in your website, use one stylesheet for all of the common styles. Otherwise, you may find it quite difficult to maintain many stylesheets. Changes would have to be added to every one of multiple stylesheets.

Stylesheets that are used only on a single page could go in separate stylesheets. This might be most useful for large single-page stylesheets and/or stylesheets for infrequently-accessed web pages.

Your stylesheets will not be reloaded on every page refresh. If you reference the large, general-purpose stylesheet on your home page, it will only be downloaded once, and cached for future use.

Answer (score 3):

"For loading purposes, wouldn't you want a smaller stylesheet, therefor making individual ones is a better practice?"

This can have a reverse effect, as using 1 stylesheet it can be cached and then re-loaded with ease, whereas it is constantly loading a new CSS file for each page with your method.

Most sites do not need to have more than one stylesheet for one type of media. However if your site drastically varies in design I would suggest having a base stylesheet which has all the common properties, and then a secondary stylesheet for each of the pages which contains the differences.

This should only be used if the CSS changes are large enough in size to warrant the use of seperate stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm actually an actual web programmer (Java's web programming stuff, not scripting such as PHP) I have to give you an opinion I've never seen any actual web *designer* give:

Please go ahead and split your CSS files to multiple, logical partitions wherever possible! If you have a hugely stylized table, collect its CSS stuff to one file, also collect the base stylings of the actual page to another file, add those menu navigation CSS:s to third one and so on and so forth. You can of course reuse individual CSS:s where they're relevant but **DO NOT** just cram everything into one big file!

Comment: I can agree with you, but reducing http requests is valuable, so you still want to concatenate all those css files before you deliver them to the client

Answer (score 1):

I came across this thread seeking the same question.. My thought was to structure like this..

Layout.css <--- for structure of the site, links, headings etc that are common across the site.
form.css <-- generic form styles
reset.css <-- all the document resets if you use them

and currently I use pages.css for all page styles..

or

homepage.css
about.css
gallery.css